# Excel flexible read-only mode

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an `Excel 2016` worksheet on a network drive that several people open and tend to keep open over the day.

There is a handful of users with `Write rights` and the need to save adjustments is perhaps like once a day or so. Users in `Read-only rights` also need to enter data in cells that would be used in Excel formulas, but obviously without the ability or need to save it.

Now the issue I'm trying to tackle is that if one of those users with Write rights actually needs to do any changes, there are limited chances he is the one that has locked the file for editing.

Any suggestions on how to make the users with Write rights not lock the file for editing unless they have an actual need to do so? I have two obvious options, however neither look usable here:

`1) Shared Workbook` - according to my experience, running Shared Workbook functionality does hinder the performance of Excel and I would not want that.

`2) Excel standard "Enable editing"` prompt before opening the Excel file with Write rights. If you don't enable editing, you are also not allowed to write stuff in cells, which is possible with regular read-only rights and is necessary.

Any suggestions? Going deep into Excel settings to turn something on/off each time when opening the file is not that appealing. Could something be done with 2 different shortcuts for the end user or some other straightforward approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are the options that come immediately to mind:

Option1

Save As and Leave the network unopened so anyone could overwrite when they need to?

Option2

If it is an '.xlsm' You could write a quick macro to copy the file to your drive and if you need to save changes "save as" and over-write the network file.

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943003/vba-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another) for some examples.